# Excel strange issue to recognise dates

Tags: excel, date, datetime

I have problem in formating the dates. I have dates that are recorded manually in dd.mm.yyy format. i have converted them to dd/mm/yyyy format using Left, right and Mid functions. The problem is that excel is able to identify only some cell values as dates and rest as text. I have also tried selecting the whole date range and convert to date. But when i apply filter the dates that are not recognised by excel are shown separately and the remaining under 2015 & 2016 years.

I need all the values to be converted and identify in excel.  I am attaching screen shots of the same issue
[Date different format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmKNL.jpg)

From the picture the row range from 23 to 28 in 2nd column is identified as date and row 29 to 34 is displayed as text. When i apply filter in second column, the date is shown as in below format

[Filter issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAlE9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

@Rejendra, I thing the problem you are having is that your computer is thying to evaluate the dates in american format e.g MM/dd/yyyy.
If you convert the date to yyyy-MM-dd using left right and mid functions and the excel formula  `=DATEVALUE` it should work

If your computer is set to non US format you could simply use:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"))
```

to convert it where A1 is the cell with the . delimited dates

Comment: =DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","/"))

Comment: When i apply the formula right from 29th row the cell value in Column 2 is shown as #Value. Any suggestions? Use the "Date Different Format" Picture as referance

Comment: I think your computer is set to use us dates  and therefore it is evaluating the date as the 3 day of the 13th month istead of what you intend the 13th day of the third month. The easiest way to fix this is to change your computers culture (language)

Comment: If you set the format on the cell long date it will confirm this for you because it will show you the date in text e.g. I expect it will tell you that 11/3/2015 is the 3rd of November